# Accessing Guardian info in Google Classroom via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I'm trying to access Google Classroom Guardian info in a Google Apps Script using the Classroom service. I've added the service and enabled the API in the API console. I can access some data (for example courses) but when I try to get guardian info via `Classroom.UserProfiles.Guardians.list(student_id )` if fails with a permission error. However, if I add a (dummy) call to `Classroom.UserProfiles.GuardianInvitations.create()` then the auth screen with the required scopes pops up and the script works thereafter. Is there something I'm missing, or is this a bug in Apps Scripts?

Comment: What is your role on the domain (teacher, student, administrator)?

Answer (score 3):

try to add

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.guardianlinks.students`

to your scopes inside the `manifest.json` file as so:

```
{
  ...
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.guardianlinks.students`"
  ],
  ...
}
```

only problem with that is you won't have the consent popup showing up and you will have to explicitly write all scopes in `manifest.json`.

One other solution is to write in comment a function that use this scope (sorry but you'll need to search for this one) as you describe your problem it looks like a bug. But solution I gave you should work.

**REFERENCES**

[Classroom.UserProfiles.Guardians.list scopes](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles.guardians/list)

[Authorization Scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)

[useful link to read](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/23ddf599a4155b66f1029978bba8153b)

Comment: Two quick notes: 

1. Your demo scope has an extra backtick in it (    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.guardianlinks.students`"
 should be     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.guardianlinks.students").

2. Here's a demo function that does what you need:


function neverRuns () {
  Classroom.Courses.Students.list('foo');
  Classroom.UserProfiles.GuardianInvitations.create('bar');
}

I found the function approach faster than finding all the scopes everything else I was using required.

Answer (score 0):

You should be a superadminstrator (domain administrator) to be able to work with Guardians through the Google Classroom API

Reference

- [Manage guardians in your domain](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/7017326?hl=en)